# change data in dataframe if variable is the same

Tags: r

lets say i have the following dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(name = c("jan", "piet", "mike", "hark", "don", "bon", "gin", "als"),
                 mark = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "k", "n", "s"))

df2 <- data.frame(name =c("piet", "mike", "hark", "don", "jan", "gin", "als", "bon"),
                  remote = c("a1b", "a5f", "a8h", "a9k", "a4k", "als", "a4t", "a3g"))
```

what gives

```
  name mark
1  jan    a
2 piet    b
3 mike    c
4 hark    d
5  don    e
6  bon    k
7  gin    n
8  als    s

  name mark
1 piet  a1b
2 mike  a5f
3 hark  a8h
4  don  a9k
5  jan  a4k
6  gin  als
7  als  a4t
8  bon  a3g
```

what I want to do is, if the name df matches the name in df2, change the value of mark to the value of remote. I thought this would do the job but it did not.

```
df$mark[df$name == df2$name] <- df2$remote
```

Comment: In your example, all of your names in df are in df2. By "matches," do you mean if they are on the same row? Can you edit to put your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
df$mark <- df2$remote[match(df$name, df2$name)]
df
  name mark
1  jan  a4k
2 piet  a1b
3 mike  a5f
4 hark  a8h
5  don  a9k
6  bon  a3g
7  gin  als
8  als  a4t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr::rows_update` (given the dataframe columns have the same names)

```r
library(dplyr)
rows_update(df, df2)

Matching, by = "name"
  name mark
1  jan  a4k
2 piet  a1b
3 mike  a5f
4 hark  a8h
5  don  a9k
6  bon  a3g
7  gin  als
8  als  a4t
```